# Cannot ready property of null - Ternary operator on an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, mapping

I am currently mapping an array of objects called `ProfileDetails` in a table. At the bottom of the table, I have a button where you can decide to `accept` these details. I am attempting to do a ternary operator to have the button `disabled` unless ProfileDetails has a TransacationType End. `TransactionType.Name === "End"`. I am getting `TransactionType` is null. Some users may have more or less than the 4 objects in an array.

Here is what I've tried:

```
           <Grid item xs={2}>
                    <Grid
                        container
                        justify="center">
                        <Grid item>
                           {ProfileDetails
                                .TransactionType
                                .Name ===
                            "End" ? ( 
                            <Button
                                variant="contained"
                                color="primary"
                                onClick={
                                    handleApprove
                                }>
                                Approve
                            </Button>
                            ) : ( 
                            <Button
                                variant="contained"
                                color="primary"
                                disabled>
                                Approve
                            </Button> 
                             )} 
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
```

Example of one of the arrays:

```
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {ProfileID: 476, Location: Home,  TransactionType: {Name: "LogIn", ShortName: null, ID: 1}
1: {ProfileID: 476, Location: Home,  TransactionType: {Name: "LogOut", ShortName: null, ID: 1} 
2: {ProfileID: 476, Location: Home,  TransactionType: {Name: "Break", ShortName: null, ID: 1}
3: {ProfileID: 476, Location: Home,  TransactionType: {Name: "End", ShortName: null, ID: 1}                                                        
 "
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `ProfileDetails` is an item in your array, change

```
ProfileDetails.TransactionType.Name === 'End' ? a : b
```

to

```
ProfileDetails.TransactionType
  && ProfileDetails.TransactionType.Name === 'End' ? a : b
```

---

If `ProfileDetails` ***is*** the array and you want to display `a` when your array contains an `End` TransactionType (and `b` otherwise), map the transaction type names and check if it includes `'End'`:

```
ProfileDetails.map(p => p.TransactionType.Name).includes('End') ? a : b
```

Comment: Change to something like this ? {ProfileDetails.TransactionType && ProfileDetails.TransactionType.Name ===End" ? ... If so I am still getting TranscationType of Null

Comment: `a` and `b` are your `<Button>`s for each case, but I didn't see any point in including them in the answer. This is a common issue, typically solved by helper functions, like `_.get(a, 'b.c.d')` from `lodash`, which returns `undefined` when `b` or `c`  are `null` or `undefined`. If `a.b.c.d` is defined, `d` is returned, obviously.

Comment: Right `a` and `b` are button the entire code too long to fit. My current set up is profileDetails.TransactionType && profileDetails.TransactionType.Name === "End" ? (button a) : (button b). Still getting the null property

Comment: Yes, sorry, I didn't notice your equality there. But anyways, `a && b` returns `b` if `a` is truthy. So the answer to your above question is: *"yes"*. I updated the answer.

Comment: What do you mean by *"Still getting the `null` property"*? Can you show the exact error? Or provide a working `codesandbox.io`?

Comment: I assumed `ProfileDetails` is one of the items in the array. If `ProfileDetails` ***is*** the array, lazarus is right. You need to loop through your array using [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). This is why you need to include a [mcve].

Comment: Doing the .map() removes the error but maps through the button for every object and displays back 4 buttons instead of 1. Any advice on how to approach that?

Comment: @neoslo Yes, I finally understood what you want. But really, man, you have to work on your *"ask-foo"*. A bit. Updated answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You are never specifiying which element in the array you are trying to read the property `TransactionType` for. You would need to target something like `ProfileDetails[0].TransactionType.Name` or map through every object in the array like:

```
{ProfileDetails.map(profile => {
    profile.TransactionType.Name === "End" ?
    (<Grid item>
        <Button enabled>
    </Grid>) :
    (<Grid item> 
        <Button disabled>
    </Grid>)
})}
```

---

Reading over your question and comments again, it seems like what you actually want to do is display the enabled button if *one* of the objects in the array has the "End" property, and otherwise display the disabled button. In which case, you could just switch out the `.map` for `.some`. You might have to `return` the grid item in each case to make it work.